# Batch file to find time/date fails on ZIP folder

Tags: batch-file

I have used this for files but when it comes to zips it doesn't work. It gives a C: local drive and doesn't output correctly.

```
FOR %%? IN (path/something.zip) DO (
    echo %%~f?,%%~t? >> output.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - your path\filespec could have been more than shortnames.

```
@echo off
FOR %%a IN ("path\something.zip") DO (
    >>output.txt echo %%~fa,%%~ta
)
```

Note that using alpha characters for the metavariables is preferred as there is less chance for confusion with wildcards.

Comment: How can I do this without a new line? >>output.txt echo|set /p= %%~fa,%%~ta doesn't work